# Android Studio Sort strings.xml Files to Match

Tags: android, xml, string, android-studio, file

In Android Studio, I have two `strings.xml` files for two languages. How do I sort the strings in one of those files to match the order of the strings in the other file?

Comment: Curious as to why it matters? There is nothing to sort them outside of writing an external application that loads the file reads it and then sorts it. Or just manually do it yourself

Comment: I want to be able to easily review the two files to double check the translations. And I want to do that without the Translation Editor in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no way to sort them outside. One way that you can do this is to Use Translation Editor in Android Studio.
Translation Editor will help you to translate words in multiple languages.

** You can use a website to sort translations of multiple languages and directly export them into Strings.xml file of each language. **

Website: https://lokalise.com/